# Qt: does "new without delete" cause memory leaks with controls?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks

I was looking at Qt example [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/tools-customtypesending-window-cpp.html):

and inside the constructor, they have:

```
 Window::Window()
 {
     editor = new QTextEdit();   // Memory leak?
     QPushButton *sendButton = new QPushButton(tr("&Send message")); // Memory leak?

     connect(sendButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(sendMessage()));

     QHBoxLayout *buttonLayout = new QHBoxLayout();  // Memory leak?
     buttonLayout->addStretch();
     buttonLayout->addWidget(sendButton);
     buttonLayout->addStretch();

     QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);    // Memory leak?
     layout->addWidget(editor);
     layout->addLayout(buttonLayout);

     setWindowTitle(tr("Custom Type Sending"));
 }
```

Those lines with comments

```
// Memory leak?
```

aren't those memory leaks?

If so, since the Window class has no constructor, then I should make all of those variables (editor already is) Window member variables ?

Or..does Qt internally "delete" those member variables when it goes out of scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of C++14 you can use the [`std::make_unique()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) convenience function template for creating an [`std::unique_ptr<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) that has exclusive ownership of the widget. Then, at the moment of passing the widget to `addLayout()`, you make the smart pointer give up ownership by calling `release()`:

```
auto buttonLayout = std::make_unique<QHBoxLayout>(); 
// ...
// an exception could be thrown here
// ...
layout->addLayout(buttonLayout.release());
```

Answer (score 30):

No, the `addWidget()` function will keep ownership of the widget. It will then destroy the widgets it owns.

Additionally you can read [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/widgets-tutorial.html) that:

> As with QObjects, QWidgets can be created with parent objects to
>   indicate ownership, ensuring that objects are deleted when they are no
>   longer used. With widgets, these parent-child relationships have an
>   additional meaning: Each child widget is displayed within the screen
>   area occupied by its parent widget. This means that when you delete a
>   window widget, all the child widgets it contains are also deleted.

Answer (score 11):

If there is an exception thrown between new and addWidget then yes there is a memory leak. Otherwise the parent control takes ownership of the memory.

```
QHBoxLayout *buttonLayout = new QHBoxLayout();  // Memory leak?
//make sure you don't throw here
buttonLayout->addWidget(sendButton);
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Klaim's correct answer:

I would store those pointers in a `std::auto_ptr`, meanwhile you pass them to their parent.

```
std::auto_ptr<QHBoxLayout> buttonLayout( new QHBoxLayout() );
// make things which could throw...
layout->addLayout(buttonLayout.release());
```

This way you are sure not to have leaks.

Comment: Even better than my own answer

Comment: Won't it get double-deleted if you do this?

Once by auto_ptr, then again by QObject?

Comment: @James calling release() will make the smart pointer releasing it's ownership, so it will not delete the object anymore. If you call get() however, you get a pointer but the smart pointer keep the ownership.

Answer (score 0):

It won't get double deleted because of the .release() call.

Note std::unique_ptr is replacing std::auto_ptr. Hopefully QT will support move semantics then that release() would be instead layout->addLayout(std::move(buttonLayout)) and without the call to move, you'd get a compile error.

Comment: it's shared_ptr that replaces auto_ptr, unique_ptr is only for scoped ptrs not for sharing, that said it's perfect for this job as we don't want to share it.