# Does owner of QBoxLayout become the owner of all layout widgets?

Tags: c++, qt

I was looking at the example [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/tools-customtypesending-window-cpp.html), and was wondering if there is no memory leaks. I have red the article talking about the subjet [mem leak on delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651616/qt-does-new-without-delete-cause-memory-leaks-with-controls). However while QWidgets do retain ownership of the of the widget added to the, the layout do not.

It seems from the QT code that the parent with the layout, gets the ownership of all the widgets for this layout. However i could not seen any reference of this in docs.

```cpp
Window::Window()
{
 editor = new QTextEdit();
 QPushButton *sendButton = new QPushButton(tr("&Send message"));

 connect(sendButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(sendMessage()));

 QHBoxLayout *buttonLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
 buttonLayout->addStretch();
 buttonLayout->addWidget(sendButton);
 buttonLayout->addStretch();

 QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
 layout->addWidget(editor);
 layout->addLayout(buttonLayout);

 setWindowTitle(tr("Custom Type Sending"));
}
```

Comment: Though the derived classes don't mention it, the base layout class (QLayout) says that `addWidget` calls `addItem`...and `addItem` says: *"**Note:** The ownership of item is transferred to the layout, and it's the layout's responsibility to delete it."*  http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qlayout.html#addItem

Comment: @HostileFork the ownership of the *item* is transferred to the layout. Not the ownership of the widget itself. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38003370/1951907) that tries to clarify this point.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From [Layout Management](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/layout.html):

> **Tips for Using Layouts**
>
> When you use a layout, you do not need to pass a parent when
>   constructing the child widgets. *The layout will automatically
>   reparent the widgets* (using QWidget::setParent()) so that they are
>   children of the widget on which the layout is installed.
>
> Note: Widgets in a layout are children of the widget on which the
>   layout is installed, not of the layout itself. Widgets can only have
>   other widgets as parent, not layouts.
>
> You can nest layouts using addLayout() on a layout; the inner layout
>   then becomes a child of the layout it is inserted into.

Comment: Did not seek this one. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: As an extra note to this, "ownership" however is given to the layout, while the parent assignment is made to the parent widget of the layout: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qlayout.html#addItem

Comment: @jdi the ownership of the *item* is transferred to the layout. Not the ownership of the widget itself. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38003370/1951907) that tries to clarify this point. The owner of a QWidget (in the memory-management sense) is always its parent widget, and therefore cannot be a layout.

Answer (score 4):

No, QLayouts do not take ownership of managed QWidgets.

Here is the implementation of `addWidget()`:

```
void QLayout::addWidget(QWidget *w)
{
    addChildWidget(w);
    addItem(QLayoutPrivate::createWidgetItem(this, w));
}
```

Explanation:

1. `addChildWidget()` simply ensures that the managed widget w is removed from other layouts.
2. `createWidgetItem(this, w)` allocates a new QWidgetItem. This QWidgetItem stores a pointer to w, but *do not take ownership of w*.
3. `addItem()` adds the item to the layout, and takes ownership of the QWidgetItem (*not of the QWidget observed by the QWidgetItem*).  This means that the QWidgetItem will de destroyed when the QLayout is destroyed. However, the QWidget w will still not be destroyed.

The QWidget will be destroyed when its parent QWidget is destroyed. Such parent is assigned automatically by the QLayout when parent->setLayout(layout) is called.

Answer (score 0):

not sure how it was in 2016 - but today (Qt 5.15 ...) layouts definitely set the parent ...